# GET or POST to save data in database and return VOID

Tags: spring-boot, get, spring-webflux, http-method

I'm wondering which Http method should I use for my case (I use Spring Boot, Webflux):

1. returns `Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>>`
2. endpoint `path: '/resources/{groupId}/x-mode'`
3. No request body
4. I want to get groupId in backend and then find some data by groupId and then send these fetched fron DB data and send to another service.

I think I should use GET but in this case GET seems to be very weird because I don't return anything...

Comment: GET `/resources/{groupId}/x-mode` is not a restful way of designing your api you should for example POST `/resources/`, body `{ groupId: 1, mode: x-mode }`  to start something.

Comment: You *never* use `GET` where side-effects happen (such as saving to a database.) `GET` requests can be cached and called multiple times, so you only ever want to *retrieve* the state of something, not alter it. If you're saving to a database, then use either `POST` or `PUT`.

Comment: YES! You're absolutely right:) Get should be used only to GET data from service